# How to stub multiple calls to same function to get different returns using minitest

Tags: ruby, mocking, minitest, stubbing

I am trying to stub a class method. The method has multiple calls to 'gets'. I wanted to manually return specific values to 'gets' calls.
My code is similar to this -

```
ParseAndPlay.stub :gets, {***NEED SOMETHING HERE***} do
    ParseAndPlay.run
end
```

and ParseAndPlay.run expects

```
def ParseAndPlay.run
    gets #=> expects "5 5"
    gets #=> "1 1 N"
    gets #=> "MMM" ... and so on
end
```

Can this be done by just using minitest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the class that was being tested. Called a new function 'get_input' which then called 'gets' and then stubbed the 'get_input' method.